# Toggle a menu of Anchors

Tags: jquery, html, button, toggle, anchor

I´m learning how to code and I have a problem.
I have createng an anchor that works like a button but I want to slide down a menu when I click that button. How can I manage that? What do I have to write on the HTML part for the menu?
Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going for a framework like Bootstrap.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Refer this page for clarity - http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp

Welcome to the world of UI coding :)

Edit - expecting such a drop down? with all anchor tags.
Code available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gaus06techian/jo3vj5te/).

[image]

Comment: just give a jist of your work or share a piece of code you are working on. will be happy to help

Comment: try the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gaus06techian/jo3vj5te/). remove the comments to get the complete html. sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a lot involved with this question, without you having an attempt of writing it yourself.

have a look around and try it yourself, if its still not working post the html on here and we can help show you where the problem is.

Comment: How can I send you the HTML?

Comment: Copy and post it into your original question but put 4 spaces before each line of the code.